# How to use two tab bars in iOS like Instagram app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm very new at swift development, I can't find a tutorial teaching how to achieve that, there is two menus in that image, one on top and one on bottom, how is it made? is this two tab bars in the same view controller? is there some example that I can follow? because I didn't find any on google

[image]

Comment: The bottom one is a tab bar, the upper one is a UIView with buttons

Comment: Here are some tutorial for you... [Tab bar by storyboard](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/tab-bar-controller-tutorial-ios8-swift) ... [Tab bar programmatically](http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/09/swift-swift-using-tab-bar-controllers-in-swift/) Happy learning :)